# What is the meaning of the background colors in the JSLint function report?

Tags: javascript, jslint

I just tested my code with JSLint and the background colors behind the function report is white, yellowish, blue and green.

I cannot find information about them?

I reckon they are not just for decoration, but what do they mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They represent different level of nesting. You will find they match the indentation of the block they appear in.